# iPhone messaging problems

Tags: iphone

Whenever I send my daughter a text, her replies back to me never appear by sound or notification that she has responded. The only way that I ever notice a reply is if I physically check my old messages, where I will find two of the same reply, the first one noted as coming from her phone, and the second, exact same reply noted as coming from my own phone number. We had tried deleting and resetting contact info but nothing seems to work. I don't seem to have a problem receiving texts from anyone else but her phone. She has an iphone 5s, I have an iphone 5c.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when I send a message to *myself* (iMessage to the same Apple ID).

Are you logged into separate Apple IDs? Check by going to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. Check both phones to see if they have the same Apple ID.

If they Do, here are instructions on fixing it:

1. You'll need to log out of iCloud and iMessage on one device
2. On this device, go to iCloud and create a new iCloud ID.
3. This keeps the ability to share purchases in iTunes & App Store, while changing the iCloud and iMessage IDs.